# How can I get the name of the key from object arguments in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

Lets say I have a function look like this:

```
function foo()
{
  console.log(arguments);  
}

foo(event_1="1", event_2="2");
```

In this case the output will be:

```
[object Arguments] {
 0: "1",
 1: "2"
 }
```

How can I get the key of the arguments (event_1, event_2) instead of (0,1)?

Comment: You cannot obtain that information; those symbols (`event_1` and `event_2`) are variable references and have nothing to do with the function invocation process (other than the incidental side effect of their being assigned values by the argument expressions).

Comment: You can't, that information isn't passed to the function.  The function has no idea you performed an assignment there (which is a bit weird to begin with).  You will have to change how the values are passed.

Comment: Thanks, I will just use a normal object for this. Even it dose not look neat

Comment: @Mero: It looks perfectly "neat".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similarly to @Robby's answer, you can also use `Object.keys`:

```
function foo() {
  console.log(Object.keys(arguments[0]));
}

foo({event_1:"1", event_2: "2"});
```

Comment: Why would anybody downvote this? It's a constructive addition to the question.

Answer (score 4):

Pass your argument as an object, and loop over the object's property names:

```
function foo() {
  for (var key in arguments[0]) {
    console.log(key);
  }  
}

foo({event_1: "1", event_2: "2"});
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case 0 and 1 are indeed the keys of the arguments. With `event_1="1"` you are not passing a key to the function, but assigning the value `"1"` to a variable `event_1` and then passing the value to the function.

If you need to pass key/value-pairs you can use the an object instead:

```
function foo(data)
{
    for (var key in data)
    {
        console.dir("key="+key+", value="+data[key]);
    }
}

foo({ first: "hello", second: "bye" });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you but you can use an object. Something like this:

```
function foo(anobj)
{
  console.log(anobj.event_1, anobj.event_2);  
}

foo({event_1:"1", event_2:"2"});
```

Comment: Almost but that's not a valid object literal.